# How to split data rows when the data has more duplicate for the detail rows?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to make details of the data being uploaded, but when there is the same data code (DMC Code), the data is not separated into one by one with different quantities. I've tried to delete Group By, but an error occurs. What should I do?
[pict1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkGKy.png)

I've tried to remove Merge, but I don't know what method it should be replaced with.
[pict2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIeIU.png)

This is the query SQL
[pict3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEmvS.png) & [pict4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZUG6.png)

Maybe somebody can help me, big thanks for the some help!

Comment: Hi @Halim, please attach your code as snippet instead of image. And as the code in the image is vb.net, please remove c# tag. Thank you. For your reference, [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Halim, you try to group by DMC Code, then follow by DMC Code Part, then follow by DMC Material. The record with same DMC Code by With Different Material or Part will be repeated of course.

Comment: @YatFeiLeong so can i make the details with the different quantities? i mean, material with same dmc code but different quantities. The quantities of records get from calculated, and not in tables.

Comment: Hi @Halim, so DMC code is your order reference and the quantity of records in in fact your qty/pcs? You want to generate a picking list for the item code with different qty/pcs for orders, is that what u mean?

Comment: Hi @YatFeiLeong, yes. but can you explain to me, what method or condition i do for that? the quantities get from calculated not the tables.

Comment: @Halim, I suppose still using group. I need the input data structure and expected result in order to proceed further. Some data example will certainly help.

Comment: @YatFeiLeong, There is not input form. Just uploaded file. I have a dupplicate DMC Code but different quantities (pict1). But in result, just the last one i get the result. The second quantities result is not showing.

Comment: @Halim, Assuming you download the data from Excel/ Plain Text. You can construct the data into a datatable or even you can make them a class collection. After that you can use LINQ to query the result. There are plenty of resources here for grouping command for LINQ.